# Beamer slide counter overflows the margin

Tags: beamer, numbering, page-numbering

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\date{fillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfiller}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The code above reproduces the following slide.
[image]

Note the page counter. It should display `1/1`, but the last couple of characters were pushed off of the slide due to the length of the parameter in `\date`.
Seeing that there's room for both the `\date` parameter and `1/1`, how do I go about making it fit?

This is a minimal working example, in reality the `\date` parameter is smaller and there's much room, but the counter still overflows the margins.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `Madrid` theme uses `infolines` as an outer theme.  In it, it uses three `beamercolorbox` environments.  In the third one, which has the date and page counter the `footline` template has `\hspace*{2em}` between the data and the page counter.    There is also a `\hspace*{2ex}` at the end which adds to this issue.

Under the right circumstances, such as this one where the data is very long, these minimal `\hspace*{2em}` and `\hspace*{1ex}` create and overfull box.  The `\hspace` in your example needs to be replaced with glue or something flexible to avoid this.  Your best bet is to us `\hspace*{\fill}` and reducing the `\hspace*{2ex}` to 1ex as with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{\fill}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\date{fillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfiller}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: fix long data in Madrid - beamer]

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the answer.